How to configure vscode to open a file with Data Wrangler by default
I am using Data Wrangler to open and inspect parquet files. To open Data Wrangler, I need to right click on the file and select "Open in Data Wrangler". I'd like to configure VSCode so that just by clicking on the parquet file, it is opened in Data Wrangler.
I've tried adding :
 "files.associations": {
        "*.parquet": "data-wrangler"
    }

to both my launch.json and settings.json. That did not work.
